Stop DataTemplate from recycling Bindings in .net MAUI
I have a model TestItem : IBaseItem, custom control TestCard of which x:DataType = "TestItem".
I also have a MainViewModel, which has an ObservableCollection<IBaseItem> BrowsingItems
In the MainPage, there is a resource dictionary with DataTemplates, one of which contains the custom TestCard and its TouchBehaviour from the Community Tookit. The data from the BrowsingItems are bound to a CollectionView with the DataTemplateSelector which compares based on the if the IBaseItem is TestItem or not.
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate"
              >


    <controls:TestCard >
        <controls:TestCard.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:TouchBehavior x:DataType="vm:TestItem"
                                   LongPressCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference mainPage}, Path=BindingContext.ShowTestContextPopupCommand}"
                                   LongPressCommandParameter="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"
                                   LongPressDuration="750" />

        </controls:TestCard.Behaviors>
    </controls:TestCard>

</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="FolderTemplate">

    <controls:FolderCard />

</DataTemplate>

<controls:BrowsingItemDataTemplateSelector x:Key="BrowsingTemplateSelector"
                                           TemplateTest="{StaticResource TestTemplate}"
                                           TemplateFolder="{StaticResource FolderTemplate}" />

<CollectionView Grid.Row="1"
                x:Name="browsingView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding BrowsingItems}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BrowsingTemplateSelector}">

</CollectionView>
.
.
.
.

<Grid  Grid.Column="0"
       RowDefinitions="*,*"
       RowSpacing="5">
    <controls:GoldMenuAddButton Image="folder_gold.svg"
                                Clicked="{Binding AddFolderCommand}"
                                Grid.Row="0" />
    <controls:GoldMenuAddButton Image="test_gold.svg"
                                Clicked="{Binding AddTestCommand}"
                                Grid.Row="1" />

</Grid>


The first Command is executed when holding mousepress on the TestCard. It displays a Popup with the Name of the item, and a set of commands to choose from (enum), which I then plan on executing back in the MainViewModel.
The second Command is for adding new TestItems based on a name chosen in another Popup. The Command is used in a binding with another button on the page.
  public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
  {




      public MainViewModel()
      {
          BrowsingItems = [];



      }

      public ObservableCollection<IBaseItem> BrowsingItems { get; private set; }


      void Sort()
      {
          var temp = BrowsingItems.OrderByDescending(x => x is FolderItem).ToList();
          BrowsingItems.Clear();
          foreach (var e in temp) BrowsingItems.Add(e);
      }


      [RelayCommand]
      async void AddTest()
      {




          var popup = new CreateBrowsingItemPopup();

          var name = await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);

          if (name != null)
          {
              BrowsingItems.Add(new TestItem() { Name = (string)name, QuestionsAmount = 0, QuestionsAnswered = 0, Random = false });
              Sort();

          }




      }


      int folderCount = 0;
      int testCount = 0;

      [RelayCommand]
      async void AddFolder()
      {
          var popup = new CreateBrowsingItemPopup();

          var name = await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);

          if (name != null)
          {
              BrowsingItems.Add(new FolderItem() { Name = (string)name });
              Sort();

          }


      }


      [RelayCommand]

      async void ShowTestContextPopup(TestItem testItem) 
      {
         
          var popup = new TestCardContextPopup(testItem.Name);

          var result =   await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);

         BrowsableCommandType? testCommand = (BrowsableCommandType?) result;

          if (testCommand == null) return;



          switch (testCommand)
          {
              case BrowsableCommandType.DELETE:
                  BrowsingItems.Remove(testItem);
                  
                  break;
          
          }



      }


}


After the deletion, the TestCard is removed and CollectionView refreshes.
If I add another TestItem with the button, its added with the appropriate name displayed.
However, if I hold on it, the name displayed on the popup is of the previous TestItem.
it also passes the same previous reference to the ShowTestContextPopup Command.
Any ideas on how to stop it from recycling old references, or how to update the Bindings on the DataTemplate?
EDIT 1:
here is TestItem.cs
public class TestItem : IBaseItem
{
    public int ID { get; init; }

    public string Name { get; init; }
    public int QuestionsAmount { get; init; }

    public int QuestionsAnswered { get; init; }

    public bool Random { get; init; }

    public double PercentageAnswered => (QuestionsAmount==0) ? 0 :     (double)QuestionsAnswered / (double)QuestionsAmount;
}

The BrowsingItemTemplateSelector
public class BrowsingItemDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public  DataTemplate? TemplateTest { get;  set; }
    public  DataTemplate? TemplateFolder { get;  set; }


    protected override DataTemplate? OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {

        return ((IBaseItem)item is TestItem) ? TemplateTest : TemplateFolder;

    }
}

TestCard.xaml
<Border xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TryMe.Resources.Models"
        x:Class="TryMe.Resources.Controls.TestCard"
        
        x:DataType="vm:TestItem"
        Padding="5"
        StrokeThickness="3"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppSecondary}"
        HeightRequest="80"
        Margin="12">


    <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="15"></RoundRectangle>
    </Border.StrokeShape>
    <Grid  RowDefinitions="*,*">
        <Image Source="test_black.svg" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35"
               Aspect="AspectFit"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Center"></Image>
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="nameLbl"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               FontSize="Medium"></Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding QuestionsAmount}"
               Grid.Row="1"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="Medium"
               HeightRequest="35"
               WidthRequest="35">
            
        </Label>
        <ProgressBar Margin="50,0,10,0" Grid.Row="1" Progress="{Binding PercentageAnswered}" HeightRequest="25" ProgressColor="Black" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppSecondary}"></ProgressBar>
    </Grid>
    
</Border>

TestCard.xaml.cs is just the constructor with InitializeComponent().
The ShowTestContextPopup.xaml:
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
               xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TryMe.Resources.Controls"
             x:Class="TryMe.Resources.Controls.Popups.TestCardContextPopup" Color="Transparent">
    <Border Stroke="{StaticResource AppGold}"
            StrokeThickness="5"
            WidthRequest="250"
            HeightRequest="150"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppPrimary}"
            Padding="5">





        <Grid BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppPrimary}"
              VerticalOptions="Center"
              HorizontalOptions="Center"
              RowDefinitions="45,50"
              ColumnDefinitions="50,50,50,50"
              ColumnSpacing="5"
              RowSpacing="5"
            >
            <Label 
                   x:Name="nameLbl"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource AppGold}"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                   FontSize="26"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>

            

            <controls:GoldMenuButton Image="edit_gold.svg"
                                     ImagePadding="8"
                                     Grid.Row="1"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     x:Name="editBttn"
                                     />
            <controls:GoldMenuButton Image="info_gold.svg"
                                     Grid.Row="1"
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     x:Name="infoBttn"
                                     />
            <controls:GoldMenuButton Image="trash_gold.svg"
                                     Grid.Row="1"
                                     Grid.Column="2"
                                     x:Name="deleteBttn" />
            <controls:GoldMenuButton Image="reset_gold.svg"
                                     Grid.Row="1"
                                     Grid.Column="3"
                                     x:Name="resetBttn" />






        </Grid>
    </Border>
</toolkit:Popup>

public enum BrowsableCommandType { EDIT, INFO, DELETE, RESET };
public partial class TestCardContextPopup : Popup
{
    
    

    public TestCardContextPopup(string name)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        nameLbl.Text = name;

        editBttn.Clicked = new Command (() => { ReturnTestCommand(BrowsableCommandType.EDIT); });

        infoBttn.Clicked = new Command(() => { ReturnTestCommand(BrowsableCommandType.INFO); });

        deleteBttn.Clicked = new Command(() => { ReturnTestCommand(BrowsableCommandType.DELETE); });

        resetBttn.Clicked = new Command(() => { ReturnTestCommand(BrowsableCommandType.RESET); });




    }






    public void ReturnTestCommand(BrowsableCommandType command) 
    {
        Close(command);


    }
}

IBaseItem :
public interface IBaseItem
{
    public int ID { get;}
}


GoldMenuAddButton:

<Border xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="TryMe.Resources.Controls.GoldMenuAddButton"
        Stroke="{StaticResource AppGold}"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppDarkPrimary}"
        Padding="5"
        StrokeThickness="3">


    <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="15"></RoundRectangle>
    </Border.StrokeShape>

    <Border.GestureRecognizers>

        <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="tapRecognizer" 
                              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />

    </Border.GestureRecognizers>
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" ColumnSpacing="25" Padding="1" >

        
        <Image x:Name="image" WidthRequest="45"
               
               Aspect="AspectFit"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               Grid.Column="0" >


        </Image>
        <Image 
               Aspect="AspectFit"
               Source="add_gold.svg"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               Grid.Column="1">


        </Image>
    </Grid>

    

</Border>


Code behind:
public partial class GoldMenuAddButton : Border
{
    public GoldMenuAddButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public BindableProperty ImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Image), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(GoldMenuAddButton)
        , propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            var control = bindable as GoldMenuAddButton;
            control.image.Source = newValue as ImageSource;

        });

    public static readonly BindableProperty ClickedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Clicked), typeof(ICommand), typeof(GoldMenuAddButton)
        , propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            var control = bindable as GoldMenuAddButton;
            control.tapRecognizer.Command = newValue as ICommand; ;

        });

    public ICommand Clicked 
    {
        get => GetValue(ClickedProperty) as ICommand;
        set => SetValue(ClickedProperty, value);
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get => GetValue(ImageProperty) as ImageSource;
        set => SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }
}


STEPS TO REPRODUCE:
v1)

Click On the button with AddFolder command, enter a name eg. Test1 in the popup.
Hold on the newly created TestCard, displays the popup with Test1. Click on the delete button.
Repeat 1)
Repeat 2), but the Name displayed on the popup and the reference passed is of the Test1 TestItem.


How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem and more code snippets about this problem (e.g. TestCard.cs  ,BrowsingItemDataTemplateSelector.cs and MainViewModel.cs) ?

Alright I will when I get the chance

And could you please post the code of IBaseItem.cs and GoldMenuAddButton?

I will add it in about 7h

What are the codes for  GoldMenuButton ,FolderCard and FolderItem? If it is convenient for you, could you please share a Minimal, Reproducible Example here so that we can help you better?

The problem is due to how behaviours handle binding, the same problem doesn't seem to occur when using regular GestureRecognizer. Apparently the creator of this feature regrets it to this day.

The issue you're experiencing with the recycled references in the CollectionView is likely due to how the MAUI framework reuses elements for performance reasons. When you delete an item and add a new one, the old view elements might still hold the previous data context due to view recycling.
To address this issue, ensure that your data bindings are refreshed correctly and that the view elements update their bindings appropriately when the data context changes. Here are a few suggestions to help resolve this:
Use Observable Properties:
Make sure your properties in TestItem implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notify the view of changes.
public class TestItem : IBaseItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int id;
    public int ID 
    { 
        get => id;
        init
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name 
    { 
        get => name;
        init
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int questionsAmount;
    public int QuestionsAmount 
    { 
        get => questionsAmount;
        init
        {
            questionsAmount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int questionsAnswered;
    public int QuestionsAnswered 
    { 
        get => questionsAnswered;
        init
        {
            questionsAnswered = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool random;
    public bool Random 
    { 
        get => random;
        init
        {
            random = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double PercentageAnswered => (QuestionsAmount == 0) ? 0 : (double)QuestionsAnswered / QuestionsAmount;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

Ensure Binding Context is Set Correctly:
When setting the data context in the XAML, ensure that the BindingContext is updated appropriately, especially when reusing views.
Explicitly Update Bindings:
You may need to force the view to refresh its binding context. One way to do this is to set the BindingContext of the view to null before reassigning it.
Avoid Data Context Caching:
Make sure the DataTemplate does not cache the old data context. You can achieve this by ensuring that the BindingContext is correctly set each time the item is reused.
Like this :
 async void ShowTestContextPopup(TestItem testItem) 
    {
        var popup = new TestCardContextPopup(testItem.Name);
        popup.BindingContext = null; // Clear the previous context
        popup.BindingContext = testItem; // Set the new context
    
        var result = await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
    
        BrowsableCommandType? testCommand = (BrowsableCommandType?)result;
    
        if (testCommand == null) return;
    
        switch (testCommand)
        {
            case BrowsableCommandType.DELETE:
                BrowsingItems.Remove(testItem);
                break;
        }
    }

Thanks

I don't think making the properties observable would help, neither would resetting the BindingContext of the popup. The problem is the TestItem reference passed to the ShowTestContextPopup Command. I need a way to refresh the Bindings on the DataTemplate.

Also, no insult, but this answer feels AI generated..

Have you try it ?
