.net MAUI Convert BindingContext back to original data containing object
Is there a way to convert the BindingContext property back to the original object containing the data?
What I have is custom control,ThingDisplay, with x:Name="thingDisplay" and x:DataType="Thing". It just displays the data from the Thing model.
Model Thing.cs:

public class Thing 
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public string Description { get; init; }

}



The main page:
<ResourceDictionary>
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template">

<controls:ThingDisplay>
    <controls:ThingDisplay.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:TouchBehavior BindingContext="{vm:MainViewModel}"
                       
                               LongPressCommand="{Binding ShowPopupCommand}"
                               LongPressCommandParameter="{Binding Path=TODO, Source={x:Reference thingDisplay}}"
                               LongPressDuration="750" />

    </controls:ThingDisplay.Behaviors>
</controls:ThingDisplay>
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>

.
.
.


<CollectionView 
                
                ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionItems}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template}">

</CollectionView>

The MainViewModel just contains this:

public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{




    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CollectionItems = [.....];



    }

    public ObservableCollection<Thing> CollectionItems{ get; private set; }

      [RelayCommand]
  async void ShowPopup(Thing th) 
  {
     
      var popup = new Popup(th);

     var res =   await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);

     

      if (res == 1) 

      CollectionItems.Remove(th);





  }





Now, what I need:

public Thing TODO=> //BindingContext conversion back to Thing


public ThingDisplay()
{

    
    InitializeComponent();



}



I need to pass the original Thing object as a viewmodel command parameter on a TouchBehaviour.
When I tried the obvious conversion route (Thing)BindingContext, it threw a null ref error.
I know that the BindingContext stores the original data in some way, as inspecting it during live XAML preview even shows it knows the type Thing.
Is there something that I'm either missing, or some alternative route?
PS: I know this is an extremely weird and convoluted way of getting the data back, but I've been experiencing weird binding caching issues with the toolkit touchbehaviour when binding to external control (more on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78540725/stop-datatemplate-from-recycling-bindings-in-net-maui)

you just cast it to the correct type, but if you are doing it before the BindingContext has been assigned, it will throw a null ref.  You appear to be evaluating it before the constructor has executed

Assign that property in the constructor and it will work

The problem is, I have already tried that. I even assigned it after InitializeComponent. I assume the DataTemplate assigns the BindingContext somewhere, as it does contain the values, but I can't access it in the constructor.

Where do you want to get the Thing object?  You could pass the Thing object via LongPressCommandParameter and retrieve it  in ShowPopup command.

You can create an object with Name and Description attributes first. then send this object by QueryProperty.
public class Thing 
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public string Description { get; init; }

}

Then You can create a package to package the data. Here is the demo you can refer to:
 async void  GoTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)  
       {  
              Label label1 = (Label)sender;  
          
              Package package=  new Package() { Name = label1.Text, Description = "your name" };  
     
              var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "MyPackage", package } };  
     
              await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"MyPage", navigationParameter);  
      }  

Last, you need to create QueryProperty [QueryProperty(nameof(MyPackage), "MyPackage")] on the top of the page you navigate to.
 public Package MyPackage  
       {  
           set  
           {  
               ShowMessage(value);  
           }  
       }  
  public async void ShowMessage(Package package)  
   {  
       var description = package.Description;  
       var name = package.Name;  
      await DisplayAlert("Query", description + name, "Ok");  
   } 

